# How not to draw out of scene bounds?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

Regarding the image below (paintbrush), I show you what I think it is the `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene`. As you can see the blue circle doesn't draw outside scene bounds. But that's not the default behavior of a `QGraphicsScene`, and I want my `QGraphicsItem` not to draw outside scene bounds. How can I achieve this?

PS: I'm new with Qt.

[image]